# I'm trying to create a KNearestNeighbors algorithm from scratch in Python, but I received an attribute error

Tags: machine-learning

The error is referring to line 45 `(prediction = my_classifier.predict(features_test));`. However, then the error proceeds with the attribute error, which then refers to line 41 `(my_classifier = ScrappyKNN())`. It states object has no attribute 'predict':

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from scipy.spatial import distance

def euc(a,b):
    return distance.euclidean(a,b)

class ScrappyKNN():
    def fit(self, features_train, labels_train):
        self.features_train = features_train
        self.labels_train = labels_train

        def predict(self, features_test):
            predictions = []
            for item in features_test:
                label = self.closest(item)
                predictions.append(label)

                return predictions

            def closest(self, item):
                best_dist = euc(item, self.features_train[0])
                best_index = 0
                for i in range(1, len(self.features_train)):
                    dist = euc(item, self.features_train[i])
                    if dist < best_dist:
                        best_dist = distance
                        best_index = i

                return self.labels_train[best_index]

iris = datasets.load_iris()

features = iris.data
labels = iris.target

features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test =           train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=.5)

my_classifier = ScrappyKNN()
# my_classifier = KNeighborsClassifier()
my_classifier.fit(features_train, labels_train)

prediction = my_classifier.predict(features_test)

print(accuracy_score(labels_test, prediction))

iris1 = [[7.1, 2.9, 5.3, 2.4]]
iris_prediction = my_classifier.predict(iris1)

# Conditional Code

if iris_prediction[0] == 0:
    print("Setosa")

if iris_prediction[0] == 1:
    print("Versicolor")

if iris_prediction[0] == 2:
    print("Virginica")
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Indent `def predict (...)`  and everything after it one tab-width to the left, then `def closest (...)` once more to the left.

Comment: Thank you for that, Gary! My name is Burt, btw. Do you think this is the reason I received the error? Thanks again and Happy Holidays to you and yours!

Comment: Yes, since you're defining the function inside a function instead of defining it for the class.

Comment: Hi Gary,,, I lined up the codes as you suggested; however, I received other errors such as: File "C:\Users\BBrag\Desktop\Machine Learning App\flowers.py", line 45, in <module>
    prediction = my_classifier.predict(features_test)
  File "C:\Users\BBrag\Desktop\Machine Learning App\flowers.py", line 18, in predict
    label = self.closest(item)
  File "C:\Users\BBrag\Desktop\Machine Learning App\flowers.py", line 28, in closest
    if dist < best_dist:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'module'
[Finished in 2.407s]

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this in class. I have the answer key for the K nearest neighbor with the iris data. Maybe that can give you a better guidance at what your are trying to do. If you scroll to part E you will see the KNN.
https://github.com/wendysegura/DS-SF-27/blob/master/classes/08/code/codealong-08-k-nearest-neighbors-answer-key.ipynb

Comment: Hi Gwenevere05! My name is Burt and I'm actually taking an online class, but I can't seem to get in contact with the professor. What he's teaching and what I'm seeing in the link you provided are a bit different, but I'm still looking. Thank you!! Burt

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what it was... In addition to the spacing issue (Thanks Gary!), rather than inputting best_dist = dist, I inputted best_dist = distance. Thanks so much for your inputs!! Dear Gwenevere, the information you provided, I’ll be using on my next project, so thank you!!